# ike-scan 0 returned handshake 0 returned notify

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2, ikev1

I need to establish vpn connection to a specific site, I used strongswan and configure my side according to the provided parameters from another side, but when I try to connect I get 'peer not responding'. I used ike-scan on the ip they gave to me as the 'encryption domain ip' and get '0 returned handshake 0 returned notify', what does this mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the IP is wrong or that there is a firewall blocking UDP traffic to port 500.

Comment: if I use ike-scan on my configured side ip I get 1 returned notify but the other side is giving me 0 returned notify as mentioned, another thing is that with nmap my ip gives port 500 udp open but the other gives 'open|filtered'